# Where is the "Do Not Email" setting?

Tags: civimail

We want to find the best way to not send bulk emails to a contact when they've asked to be removed from our mailing lists. I've seen many references to the "Do Not Email" box, but have not been able to find it. We are able to use the "On Hold" setting for a specific email address of the contact, but the documentation implies that that is for a different purpose (that the email address does not work). Is there a "Do Not Email" setting that we can manually select in order to have a contact excluded from any future CiviMail mailings?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hidden inside Communication Preferences on the contact record:

[image]

Comment: "best way to not send bulk emails to a contact" would mean you should use the NO BULK EMAILS rather than the 'Do not email' if you want to retain option of emailing them one-to-one